# How to create a launcher application for two Air desktop aplications

Tags: c#, c++, windows, air, actionscript-3

I know that my question is very general and I don't expect very detailed answer either, just a lead would be great.
Here is what I want to achieve.
I have build two desktop applications using Adobe Air from Flash AS3 files. Both applications are parts of the same project. They're displaying over two screens, each app on one screen, and whatever you do in one it reflects the other, because they are communication each other through local connection class (AS3).
In fact those two applications are One Multi-screen Application. However to install them on the desktop computer you have to first install one Air app and after that the second Air app. The procedure with launching the apps is the same. You have to click on one icon for the first app to open , and than you click on the other icon for the second app to open, and only then you have whole application up and working.

So I'm looking for some solution which would allowed me to "pack" two installation Air files into one package. The user would have to click only on one "instal.exe" icon to fire up installation of those two air apps.

Maybe it needs to be use some external small C++ scrip, or application launcher - I have no Idea

Pease help me with this case, as I couldn't find it anywhere. I would be very grateful even far the smallest lead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not real sure but could this help ?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air3-install-and-deployment-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending how large / complicated your applications are maybe you could redactor it into one application and use [Native window](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) to then launch two windows each one containing the separate app logic.

This may even offer advantages over using the local connection class, and of course help ease development and maintenance of two separate apps.